# MySQL query to select first word in a field and return count

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a MySQL query that counts occurrences of only the first word of a string, then order by count descending.

This is my attempt and does not work:

```
   SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`logotitle`, ' ', 1)) as var
   FROM tbllogos
   ORDER BY var DESC
```

Example:

Four database entries:

1. Fruit Logo
2. Apple Logo
3. Apple Fruit Logo
4. Banana Logo

The query should return:

Apple 2

Banana 1

Fruit 1

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(logotitle, ' ', 1), COUNT(*) as var`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`logotitle`, ' ', 1) as var, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM tbllogos
GROUP BY var
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(logotitle, ' ',1) AS var, COUNT(*) FROM tbllogos GROUP BY var;
```

Result:

```
+--------+----------+
| var    | COUNT(*) |
+--------+----------+
| Apple  |        2 |
| Banana |        1 |
| Fruit  |        1 |
+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(logotitle, 1, INSTR(logotitle, ' ')) AS var, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tbllogos
GROUP BY var
ORDER BY count DESC
```